# Find top scored from parent and all their children in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, model

I have a model called User, which has self-join association as this:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "User",
    foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "User"
```

And it also has an association with a Post model:

```
User has_many post
```

Each Post object has a score attribute, and I am trying to find the posts for a given user and their children which have a highest score, which score is bigger than 0, and which satisfy a particular attribute.  So right now, I have this method in my Post model:

```
def self.top_related_scored_by_user_id(user_id, max)
    where(:user_id => user_id).
      where(:related_image => true).
      where('score > 0').
      order(score: :desc).
      first(max)
  end
```

But, I would like to be able to look not just for the User with user_id, but also for their children. How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple:

```
def self.top_related_scored_by_user_id(user_ids, max = nil)
  user_ids = user_ids.kind_of?(Array) ? user_ids : [user_ids]
  scope = where(:user_id => user_ids)
  scope = scope.where(:related_image => true)
  scope = scope.where('score > 0')
  scope = scope.order(score: :desc)
  scope = scope.limit(max) if max.present?
  scope
end
```

You can give an array of ids to the where clause, it will generate a condition like this:

```
WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

---

**A little improvement** of your method, to make it more flexible:

```
def self.top_related_scored_by_user_id(user_ids, options = {})
  options = { limit: 10, order: 'score DESC', 
              score: 0, related_image: true  }.merge(options)
  user_ids = user_ids.kind_of?(Array) ? user_ids : [user_ids]

  scope = where(:user_id => user_ids)
  scope = scope.where(:related_image => options[:related_image])
  scope = scope.where('score > ?', options[:score])
  scope = scope.order(options[:order])
  scope = scope.limit(options[:limit])
  scope
end
```

This way you can easily set options with the same function, and it has default values that can be overridden if needed.

Comment: Oh ok. So I need to figure out the ids (parent and children) before using the method, right?

Comment: Yes you need to retrieve these ids before using this method.

Comment: If it's likely that the array of ids will be large you may want to use a subquery to offload the work to your database.